# Codeception multiselect none - select no options

Tags: multi-select, codeception

I'm trying to test a multiselect having all of its options unselected. I've found how to select multiple options by passing through an array of options, but passing an empty array generates an error.

```php
$I->selectOption('Helper', []);
```

```
[PHPUnit\Framework\Error\Notice] Array to string conversion
```

Passing `null` doesn't work either:

```php
$I->selectOption('Helper', null);
```

```
 [InvalidArgumentException] Input "task[helpers]" cannot take "" as a value (possible values: "1", "2", "3", "4").
```

Is there a way to deselect all options for a multiselect on a form that loads with some of its options already selected?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found a workaround by reading the source code of [Codeception/lib-innerbrowser](https://github.com/Codeception/lib-innerbrowser/commit/3e8f4ccd2e8a3f566f43968f108cb9664f9c7705).

```php
$I->selectOption('Helper', ['value' => []]);
```

However, this looks like a bug to me (that an empty array does not work as is).